# apache2 restart error. how to resolve this

Tags: 12.04, apache2

Running `apachectl -k restart` gives:

```
/usr/sbin/apachectl: 87: ulimit: error setting limit (Operation not permitted)
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
httpd not running, trying to start
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
Action '-k restart' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

This is what I am getting while restarting the server. How can I fix this?

Comment: did you run that command as root ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the answer / reason..!
Acutally, the reason for not restarting here, something other. it is ..

The default port for my apache2 here is 80, and is being used by some other process/server called some "xyzserver". then Apache tried to start on the same port,but it could not able start. later I found the that, and I killed that process then restarted apache2. It successfully working now.

I tried in the way

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

I got the same error i.e., the way I regularly use.

Answer (score 4):

To restart apache, please use:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```